# Passing in headers to a remote request

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an HTTP GET request in Wordpress that looks like this:

```
$remote = vip_safe_wp_remote_get($api_base . "get.json?genre=" . $genre, false, 1, 3)
```

works fine, but I now need to pass in a couple of headers that look like this:

```
apikey: [key]
authtoken: [token]
```

How can I pass these in? I've tried doing $headers = array() with the arguments passed in as key value pairs, but that returns an HTTP 503 error. The service works when I try to access it from the command line with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$params = array('headers' => array(
    'apikey' => '[key]',
    'authtoken'=> '[token]'
));

$remote = vip_safe_wp_remote_get(
    $api_base . "get.json?genre=" . $genre, false, 1, 3, 20, $params);
```

See the reference of vip_safe_wp_remote_get: http://vip.wordpress.com/functions/vip_safe_wp_remote_get/

According to the reference the last argument is a

> set other arguments to be passed to wp_remote_get()

See the reference of wp_remote_get:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get